# How to get specific main site text on string

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to get the main site text on a string.

Strings

> string site1 = "https://www.google.com/xxxxxxxx";
>
> string site2 = "https://www.youtube.com/xxxxxxxxx";

Getting Result should be

> string getsite1 = "https://www.google.com";
>
> string getsite2 = "https://www.youtube.com";

Comment: The [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) class might do what you need

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `authority` part of the URL which is the scheme and the host like this

```
    string site1 = "https://www.google.com/xxxxxxxx";
    string site2 = "https://www.youtube.com/xxxxxxxxx";

    string getsite1 = new Uri(site1).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    string getsite2 = new Uri(site2).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

    Console.WriteLine(getsite1);
    Console.WriteLine(getsite2);
```

this prints

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) class.

```
string site1 = "https://www.google.com/xxxxxxxx";
var uri = new Uri(site1);
var getsite1 = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like npinti wrote in the comment you need the Uri Class. Then you can create something like this:

```
string site1 = "https://www.google.com/xxxxxxxx";

var uri = new Uri(site1);

var result = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Comment: Doesn't get the scheme like OP wants